# Why dict() instead of Dict() for a marshamllow Schema?

Tags: python, marshmallow

Cannot define Dict() as field for a marshmallow-model Schema.

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Dict
from typing import Dict
....
class OutSchema(Schema):
    queryID = String()
    img_path = String()
    object_detection = Boolean,
    visual_relations = Boolean,
    output = Dict()
```

Error when executing:

```bash
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "myfile.py", line 81, in <module>
        class EnrichmentOutSchema(Schema):
      File "myfile.py", line 86, in OutSchema
        output = Dict()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 727, in __call__
        raise TypeError(f"Type {self._name} cannot be instantiated; "
    TypeError: Type Dict cannot be instantiated; use dict() instead
```

If I change Dict() for dict (as Exception says) it works. The question is, Why? Dict() is a marshmallow field, [see](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Dict). The following class works.

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Dict
from typing import Dict

    class OutSchema(Schema):
        queryID = String()
        img_path = String()
        object_detection = Boolean,
        visual_relations = Boolean,
        output = dict()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are importing is `typing.Dict` not `marshmallow.fields.Dict`

When importing anything with the same name from different modules, you can use 'as' for naming different:

```py
from marshmallow.fields import Dict as MarshmallowDict
from typing import Dict

    class OutSchema(Schema):
        queryID = String()
        img_path = String()
        object_detection = Boolean,
        visual_relations = Boolean,
        output = MarshmallowDict()
```